# Read all the entries of a matrix using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, fortran

I have a matrix,

```
A(i,j), i=1,m and j=1,n
```

I can read it in C and FORTRAN, but I can't read it in shell script. I know this is a very simple question, but I am very new to shell script. I want to read all entries and do some calculation e.g. I have a matrix:

```
A= 1 0 1 1
   2 1 0 2
   1 0 0 3
   1 2 3 0
```

Now I want to compare each 0 with its above, below, left and right values. Finally I want to do some computation (lets say sum) with these four values around each zero. In the above example the result will be- for five zeros

```
1st zero: 3
2nd zero: 4
3rd zero: 4
4th zero: 6
5th zero: 6
```

So in FORTRAN, I can do it by reading all the values as

```
do j=1,n
  do i=1,m
    if (A(i,j) .eq. 0) then
    B(i,j)=A(i-1,j)+A(i+1,j)+A(i,j+1)+A(i,j-1)
  enddo
enddo
```

But I want to do it in shell script. How to do?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. What is the format of your input and what exactly are you trying to do? What is the relationship between reading all entries in a script and performing calculations in Fortran?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what your input looks like and what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TomFenech : Thank you. Now I added some explanations of my requirements to the question.

Comment: Why would you want to do matrix calculations in shell script? It's possible, but it's going to be painful because the shell's data structure support is poor.

Comment: I have more than thousand files in different different directories. I would like to collect such samples in each file for some further analysis. So what my code does is it enters into each directory using shell script, executes the FORTRAN code and saves the samples in a text file. It is going well. But I was trying to do it by shell. Thank you @chepner

Comment: Ah, I understood @HighPerformanceMark . By the way, you pointed out my next question already. Can you please answer me there. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401126/is-it-a-good-way-to-use-cd-and-cd-commands-in-a-shell-script-for-some-computat

Comment: I see !! and you are right @HighPerformanceMark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that data are given in "test.dat" (with no "A = "), I tried it anyway...

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                       
inpfile="test.dat"

L=100  # some large value
for (( i = 0; i < L; i++ )) {
for (( j = 0; j < L; j++ )) {
    A[ L * i + j ]=0
}
}

i=1
while read buf; do
    inp=( $buf ); n=${#inp[@]}
    if (( L <= n+1 )); then echo "L is too small"; exit -1; fi

    for (( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )) {
        A[ L * i + j ]=${inp[j-1]}
    }
    (( i++ ))
done < $inpfile

nzeros=0
for (( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )) {
for (( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )) {
    if (( ${A[ L * i + j ]} == 0 )); then
        (( nzeros++ ))
        B[ nzeros ]=$(( \
            ${A[ L * (i-1) + j   ]} + \
            ${A[ L * (i+1) + j   ]} + \
            ${A[ L * i     + j+1 ]} + \
            ${A[ L * i     + j-1 ]} ))
    fi
}
}

for (( k = 1; k <= nzeros; k++ )) {
    printf "%dst zero: %d\n" $k ${B[k]}
}
```

Conclusion: Very painful. Fortran is recommended...(as expected)

Comment: OMG!! It's so big. Thank you very much for your attempt.

Comment: If you definitely want to avoid compilation (for some reason), I recommend Python + Numpy or other scripting languages (zsh might be slightly better than bash but I am not sure...)