# Is it a good way to use cd and cd - commands in a shell script for some computation in another directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I use cd in my shell script to enter into a directory for some computation and again use cd - to come back. Is it a good way to use? My script is:

```
input_dir=/home/abc/2001/01/
cd $input_dir
#Execute some programm with ifile.txt e.g.
awk '$1 > 99 {printf "%.2f" "$1"}' ifile.txt > ofile.tx 
cd -
```

or we should always mention the path name? like:

```
input_dir=/home/abc/2001/01/
awk '$1 > 99 {printf "%.2f" "$1"}' $input_dir/ifile.txt > $input_dir/ofile.txt
```

Can you please suggest if there is anything easy way to reduce the texts?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's one of the intended uses of `-` as an argument to `cd`.

Comment: if you want to know  for sure, you could also use pushd and popd?

Comment: @KlaasvanGend . do you suggest to use pushd and popd in stead of cd and cd - respectively.

Comment: The beauty of pushd over cd is that you can use cd within a pushd-popd pair. This makes larger scripts more reliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it in a subshell:

```
(cd "$input_dir" && exec awk '$1 > 99 {printf "%.2f" "$1"}' ifile.txt > ofile.tx)
```

Thus, when the subshell exits, you're automatically back to your original directory, because the `cd` only applied to that subshell (containing only the `awk` command).

The `exec` ensures that you're not incurring extra overhead, as it causes the subshell to replace its process table entry with the `awk`. (Some shells will do this automatically for the last command inside a subshell).

Answer (score 1):

A common technique to limit the scope of `cd` for a given computation is to run the command in a subshell, like this:

```
(cd "${inputdir}" && awk '…')
```

This is however not always applicable, because the subshell has limited ways to to communicate with the parent shell.  The subshell introduce a frontier confining manipulations involving the following resources:

- job control
- variables
- of SIGNAL handlers

If you need the computation occurring in the directory to interact with these resources *of the parent script*, you still can still delimit the scope of the `cd` with a subshell provided that you:

- either use a named FIFO to let the child notify required job control, variables, signal manipulation to the parent script
- or rewrite the computation so that only input and simple processing occur in the subshell, while the parent shell reads and interpret the results through an anonymous pipe.

Comment: I have a doubt now. Both of your commands are working fine with me. But I could not understand how does the defined variables in the parent script work in another directory? It seems the parent script is completely working in that directory also.

Comment: What I mean is that, for instance, if your computation is “read some configuration file and set shell's variable accordingly” then limiting the scope of `cd` with a subshell works against you. To solve this, you can split the job in two functions talking through a named pipe, or use another similar strategy.

Comment: I see!! and understood your point. For instance, my code is not doing such complicated computations. But, it is of course an important point to remember.

Comment: @MichaelLeBarbierGrünewald, ...however, `awk` can't itself set a shell variable in the parent at all, and someone would write such a thing as `var=$(cd "$inputdir" && exec awk ...)` anyhow, which works fine. It's only if invoking a shell builtin or function, as opposed to an external command, that this is a legitimate objection.